# Android linear layout override onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, save, state, android-linearlayout

I have several custom components which extends `LinearLayout`.

Now I want to save/restore their state when screen orientation changes, but I can't do it from activity's `onSaveInstanceState`/`onRestoreInstanceState` because I need it to be flexible. It means I have to override those functions in the `LinearLayout` directly, but I couldn't find any examples.

Can somebody show me a code snippet how can I use it to store several strings and booleans? Of course every component have an unique ID.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create custom `Parcelable` for the component and use it in `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`. A bit more detailed explanation can be found here: http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html